# Eclipse & web development

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to learn servlets and JSP and would like to do this with Eclipse. When I click about in my current version, I get this info:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 2
```

After searching a bit, it seems you cannot access these features with this version - you need "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers".

I've found a tutorial to install these plugings in your Eclipse installation, but I'm just getting a "failed"-message with no error message. After this, I decided to just download a new version (the EE one ofcourse) from the Eclipse website. The old installation is in c:\program files (x86)\eclipse, the new one in c:\program files (x86)\eclipse2.

The old one still works fine, but when I try to run the new one, I get this:

[image]

I have no clue what is wrong here. Am I doing something wrong? The only thing I want is to use Eclipse for JSP and Servlet Development (soon also EJB).

Thanks

Comment: Is java installed in your system ?

Comment: Check the architecture of the Eclipse you downloaded.  If it's the X86_64, is won't be able to use the 32-bit Java, and vice-versa.  You can still make it all work, you just need the right JDK version for your Eclipse, and set the -vm arg in the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: That might be the reason, thank you. I'm now downloading a 32-bit version of Eclipse. Let's see if that works...

Comment: Thanks you, it works fine with a 32-bit version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse cannot find your JRE/JDK. Put the JRE/JDK folder in your PATH variable. My JDK is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
```

Should be a similar path for you. Add that to your PATH variable.

Have look at this [tutorial](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) to find out how.

Comment: But the old installations still works. I've added this to my PATH variable, but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: I hope you added your path, not mine. The old install probably has its own JRE in its installation folder. Open up a console, and type `java` and `javaw` in it. Whats the response?

Comment: Yes, I have added my own version and double-checked the path, it's correct. Typing java/javaw in the console results in a "not found"-error. But the strange thing is that my old installation works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a [Java 6 JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) is installed. If it is then you should be able to type **javac -v** on a command prompt and see output like this '**javac 1.6.0_26**'

Once you have this correctly eclipse should start with no issues.